# Ensuring user is updating its own record

Tags: asp.net, csrf-protection

I'm building a simple web form which allows user to edit there data like email, emergency contact etc.

The edit form is rendered using Asp.NET MVC 5.  Proper html fields are rendered for Id, email, emergency contact etc.

Lets say the request to save the data is received by the following controller method.

```
SaveData(recordId, email, emergencyContact)
{
  ;
}
```

Question:  How do I make sure that recordId was indeed the id that was rendered as part of the edit form? We don't want this user to update another user's record.

I have the following options in mind
1. Create a hash of the record id and send the hash as well.
2. Ensure user is authorized to modify the record indicated in given record id.

Is there any other way?  Does MVC 5 provide any features so that I don't have to put this sort of logic in my application logic?

Comment: The most obvious feature I can think of is Authentication - if you're using Forms or Windows Authentication, you can look up the recordId for User.Identity.Name and make sure it matches the recordId submitted in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Typical approaches are:

- Store the ID of the record as a hidden field.  If you  are concerned with hijacking, encrypt the value and decrypt on the server.
- Store the ID of the record in session; this way, you always pull back the record and keep the value on the server.  But when session dies, so does the link to the record.

Yes I'd highly recommend check permissions to the record if you store the ID in the URL.